# Get link if user selected text is contained within a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I am trying to figure out how to get a link href if the user has highlightened text is contained within a text...

So for example if the following is a link

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Find us on Google</a>
```

and the user hightlights the text "Google"

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Find us on Google</a>
```

So the question is:
After the user highlights text (as in to copy and paste it) they well hit a button and it will return what the link is for the selected text.

I hope I made this clear, wasn't really sure how to phrase it.

Comment: what do you mean with highlights? click? hover? select?

Comment: if you were to highlight text to copy and paste it.

Comment: And then click on what, or just when the text is selected ? I don't get it ?

Comment: An external button, going to update question to clear this up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.href;
```

or in IE:

```
document.selection.createRange().parentElement().href;
```

should get the element's href where the text is selected ?

Comment: Always amazing and super fast help here on Stackoverflow! Thank you so much!